# KDB query : Get blank column values from other table if value is null

Tags: kdb

I have 2 tables as a result of query as following :

```
select customer,date,product,orderId,version,size from tableA where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative)



+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------+
| customer |   date   |  product   | orderId | version | size |
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------+
| XYZ fund | 4/8/2020 | Derivative |       1 |       6 |      |
| XYZ fund | 4/8/2020 | Derivative |       2 |       6 | 1000 |
| XYZ fund | 4/8/2020 | Derivative |       3 |       4 |      |
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------+


select sum size by date,product,parent_orderId,parent_version from tableB where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative)


+----------+------------+----------------+----------------+------+
|   date   |  product   | parent_orderId | parent_version | size |
+----------+------------+----------------+----------------+------+
| 4/8/2020 | Derivative |              1 |              1 |   10 |
| 4/8/2020 | Derivative |              1 |              2 |   10 |
| 4/8/2020 | Derivative |              1 |              3 |   10 |
| 4/8/2020 | Derivative |              1 |              4 |   10 |
| 4/8/2020 | Derivative |              1 |              5 |   10 |
| 4/8/2020 | Derivative |              1 |              6 |   10 |
| 4/8/2020 | Derivative |              3 |              1 |   20 |
| 4/8/2020 | Derivative |              3 |              2 |   20 |
| 4/8/2020 | Derivative |              3 |              3 |   20 |
| 4/8/2020 | Derivative |              3 |              4 |   20 |
+----------+------------+----------------+----------------+------+
```

So basically I want that if the Result 1 has missing size then it should be populated from Result 2 based on matching columns i.e date=date,product=product,orderId=parent_orderId,version=parent_version. Is there any way to do it using query in KBD?
Following is expected o/p :

```
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------+
| customer |   date   |  product   | orderId | version | size |
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------+
| XYZ fund | 4/8/2020 | Derivative |       1 |       6 |   10 |
| XYZ fund | 4/8/2020 | Derivative |       2 |       6 | 1000 |
| XYZ fund | 4/8/2020 | Derivative |       3 |       4 |   20 |
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [left join](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/lj/) operator to achieve this:

```
q)res1:select customer,date,product,orderId,version,size from tableA where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative);
q)res2:select sum size by date,product,orderId:parent_orderId,version:parent_version from tableB where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative);
q)res1 lj res2
customer date     product    orderId version size
-------------------------------------------------
XYZ fund 4/8/2020 Derivative 1       6       10  
XYZ fund 4/8/2020 Derivative 2       6       1000
XYZ fund 4/8/2020 Derivative 3       4       20
```

Note that we had to ensure that the column names in the second tables matched those we wanted to join on in the first table.

Comment: I already tried lj and pj too but getting error :                                       
select customer,date,product,orderId,version,size from tableA where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative)
lj
select sum size by date,product,parent_orderId,parent_version from tableB where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative)



Error: kdb error: type

Comment: There are two things wrong with the line you posed here. 1) The q programming language strictly reads from right to left, so for left-join to work correctly you will have to place the left hand argument in parentheses. 2) You also need to make sure that the column names match. q has no way of knowing automatically knowing that you want `version` to match on `parent_version` for example. The code I provide above re-names the columns in your second table to handle this.

Comment: My bad in posting : column name I matched but can you let me know about parentheses where its missing and post correct query : select customer,date,product,orderId,version,size from tableA where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative) lj
select sum size by date,product,orderId:parent_orderId,version:parent_version from tableB where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative)

Comment: ``(select customer,date,product,orderId,version,size from tableA where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative)) lj select sum size by date,product,orderId:parent_orderId,version:parent_version from tableB where date=2020.04.08,product in (`Derivative)``

Comment: Thanks a lot for assistance. It worked. I missed silly parentheses :-(